# how to migrate all pip2 packages to pip3 not having anymore pip2

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, homebrew

I recently updated my packages on a macOS High Sierra using `brew update && brew upgrade` in where now `python` and `pip` are symlinks to python3, pip3. From `brew info python`

> Unversioned symlinks python, python-config, pip etc. pointing to python3,
>   python3-config, pip3 etc., respectively, have been installed.

I tend to install all my packages within my `$HOME` directory by using: `pip install --user <package>`, so my first instinct to reinstall the packages was to do a `pip freeze` to get the list of packages and then just try to install them using `pip3` but after the upgrade I notice I don't have `pip2` anymore.

Is there a way without having to install python2, to list user instaled packages, something like `pip freeze` so that later I could just reinstall them using pip (now pip3)?, (I still have the `$HOME/Library/Python/2.7` directory with all its contents)

Comment: There old `pip` binary should still be somewhere else in your `$PATH`, right?

Comment: I do have `/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.14_3/bin` but all files make reference to `#!/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7` wich doesn't exist anymore in the system

Comment: Cellar is the one from `brew`, but your native `python` binary should be there too, it's not like you removed standard Mac OS python, no?

Comment: Standard python in mac doesn't come with `pip2`, you have `easy_install` and therefore can install `pip2` but that's what I would like to avoid

Answer (score 0):

You may have a folder `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages` with your old packages... In such a case you can list the installed packages with `ls`